# Function to Accept Any Type but `AnyVal`?

Tags: scala

Looking at the Akka [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html) for creating an Actor:

> The recommended approach to create the actor Props is not supported for cases when the actor constructor takes value classes as arguments.

Is it possible to define a function:

`def anyTypeButValueClass[A : ...](x: A) = ???`

where `A` is any type except for a value class at **compile-time**?

My understanding is that value classes extend `AnyVal`,(per [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html)) but there's also:

> The standard implementation includes nine AnyVal subtypes:
>
> `Double, Float, Long, Int, Char, Short, and Byte` are the numeric value types.
>
> `Unit and Boolean` are the non-numeric value types.

per [AnyVal](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/AnyVal.html).

How can this function be written?

Comment: for the `AnyVal` specific case, Lee's answer is spot on. If you want to exclude a particular type, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781782/type-parameter-does-not-extend-given-type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Scala [*type hierarchy*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types.html) shows that `Any` has two direct subtypes, `AnyRef` and `AnyVal` for reference and value types respectively.

This means you can just add an `AnyRef` constraint:

```
def anyTypeButValueClass[A <: AnyRef](x: A) = ???
```

Comment: Isn't this wrong per this, I believe, counter-example? `scala> anyTypeButValueClass(true)
<console>:13: error: inferred type arguments [Boolean] do not conform to method anyTypeButValueClass's type parameter bounds [A <: AnyRef]`

Comment: @KevinMeredith - Isn't that the behaviour you want? `Boolean` extends `AnyVal`.

Comment: My mistake - I was thinking there's a way to distinguish a value class (`extends AnyVal`) from a primitive, e.g. `true, Int, etc.`

Comment: I'm curious to know what the restriction is. Is it just a problem with boxing? Then maybe the API works with primitives but not other value types.

Comment: @som-snytt https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/th_zKjeCVSg

Answer (score 2):

"Accept any type but `AnyVal`" is answered at [Enforce type difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference), but it's very different from "Accept any type which doesn't extend `AnyVal`", which is again different from "Accept any type except for a value class". Value classes do extend `AnyVal`, but so do the primitive types.

You can do it in this way:

```
// just a marker trait
sealed trait NotAValueClass[A]

object NotAValueClass {
  implicit def AnyRefIsNotAValueClass[A <: AnyRef]: NotAValueClass[A] = new NotAValueClass[A] {}
  implicit val IntIsNotAValueClass: NotAValueClass[Int] = new NotAValueClass[Int] {}
  ... // same for other primitive types
}

def anyTypeButValueClass[A : NotAValueClass](x: A) = ...
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexey. Does any library (`shapeless`, etc.) already provide `NotAValueClass[A]` out of the box?

Comment: I don't know, but I wouldn't expect it.

Comment: @KevinMeredith, not specifically for `AnyVal`, but shapeless provides a "not subtype of" utility. See my answer for details.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Right, but the point of my answer is that it's different from `NotAValueClass`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use a library like [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), you could also encode it like

```
import shapeless._

def anyTypeButValueClass[A: |¬|[AnyVal]#λ](x: A) = x
```

ref: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/package.scala#L54

example:

```
@ def anyTypeButValueClass[A: |¬|[AnyVal]#λ](x: A) = x
defined function anyTypeButValueClass

@ anyTypeButValueClass(42)
Compilation Failed
Main.scala:296: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method nsubAmbig1 in package shapeless of type [A, B >: A]=> shapeless.<:!<[A,B]
 and method nsubAmbig2 in package shapeless of type [A, B >: A]=> shapeless.<:!<[A,B]
 match expected type shapeless.<:!<[Int,AnyVal]
anyTypeButValueClass(42)
                ^
@ anyTypeButValueClass("foo")
res0: String = "foo"
```